# Unable to create MS Team free organization account

Tags: azure, microsoft-teams, organization

I'm aware that there are two types of Teams accounts:

1. MS Team free personal account. https://teams.live.com/
2. MS Team free organization account. https://teams.microsoft.com/

Unfortunately, when I try to create the organization account (type 2) using this link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sign-up-for-teams-free-classic-70aaf044-b872-4c32-ac47-362ab29ebbb1, it just redirects me back to the free personal account (type 1).

Specifically, I need to create the type of free Teams account where you can create an Org, and then inside the Org you can have multiple Teams.

Every time I try to create the account, I always get redirected back to teams.live.com. I've tried multiple links on the Microsoft website, even from the "Business" section. Additionally, I tried with a different email address to see if there was a problem with the account that I was trying to use.

What happened to the free organization accounts?

Answer (score 1):

What email address are you using to create your teams business account? Is it your personal email? If so that might be the case.

You need to use an email address linked to a work or school account (organization account) to be able to create a Teams business account. You also need to be a global admin in that work/school tenant.

see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/create-an-org-wide-team

[image]

Other useful links :

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/which-account-do-you-want-to-use-2b5bbd7a-7df6-4283-beff-8015e28eb7b9

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/what-s-the-difference-between-a-personal-microsoft-account-and-a/ba-p/2241897